# Why are the bullets for the unordered list being displaying before the items were added into the list?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

**Why are the bullets being displayed before the list items were added?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> <%=kindOfDay%> </h1>
    <ul>
      <% for (var i =0; i<= newListItems.length; i++){ %>
        <li> <%= newListItems[i] %></li>
      <%  } %>
    </ul>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" >
      <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrqSG.png)

Comment: `i<= newListItems.length;` should probably be `i < newListItems.length;`

Comment: or `i<= (newListItems.length - 1)`

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an off-by-one error, try this instead:

```
<% for (var i=0; i < newListItems.length; i++){ %>
   <li> <%= newListItems[i] %></li>
<%  } %>
```